# discord.js 13.8.1 defer reply

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to edit a message after you click a button, but there is a problem.

My code works exactly how it supposed to, but every time it says "this interaction falied" because there is no responce. How can you defer reply to that interaction without actually replying? Or is it even possible?

Just want an example how you can do that, and if not possible, how can you avoid this

I edit it as message:

```js
interaction.channel.messages.fetch(/*here is a message id from buttons custom id*/).then(
   async ms => {
      return ms.edit({ content: 'an edited responce to interaction reply' })
   }
)
```

there is no responce for button interaction, so it displays `This interaction failed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ButtonInteraction#deferUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v13/class/ButtonInteraction?scrollTo=deferUpdate). This method will defer the update and reset the component's loading state, without throwing the `This interaction failed` error.

```js
interaction.channel.messages.fetch(/*here is a message id from buttons custom id*/).then(
   interaction.deferUpdate();
   async ms => {
      return ms.edit({ content: 'an edited responce to interaction reply' })
   }
)
```